# Firebase remove child permission denied

Tags: firebase, swift3, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

The JSON looks like this: [image]

I want to remove the child which is [steven : uid] from user_lookup

This is the code:

```
self.ref.child("user_lookup").queryOrderedByValue().queryEqual(toValue: user?.uid).observe(.value, with: { snapshot in

                            if snapshot.exists() {

                                print("I got it")
                                // remove [steven, uid]

                            } else {

                                print("Not found")

                            }
```

I don't know how to remove the child, but i've tried to type removeValue but i got Permission_denied

Here is the rules:

```
`"user_lookup": {
      ".read": "auth !== null",
            ".write": "auth !== null && !data.exists()",

        ".indexOn": [".value"],
```

I think its because "!data.exists()" but I don't want to duplicate data, so how to fix that?
And how can i remove the child, Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Your rules are quite explicitly rejecting write operations if data already exists. Instead of saying what you don't want with the data, can you describe what you **do** want? For example: "I want authenticated users to be able to write their name with their own UID and delete their name (with their own UID)."

Comment: make sure also, that the user is signed in

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I want auth users to write their name and their uid if the [name or uid] doesn't exists yet. Like i cannot write 'steven' because its already exists for another user, And I want auth users to remove their name with uid.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Any help please?

Answer (score 1):

I think this might be what you want:

```
".write": "
  (auth.uid === newData.val() && !data.exists()) || 
  (auth.uid === data.val() && !newData.exists()"
```

The first expressions or the or allows user to claim their name if it doesn't exist yet. The second expression allows then to delete their claim.

Comment: thanks for help! but its not working, I can't even write anything with simulator https://i.gyazo.com/55b970896146430ff7e6c7a223fab44e.png

Comment: And if i add the already exists name via database for example "justin" for another uid the uid will be updated, so the name stolen I don't want that to happen, I want each user have different name that wont be duplicated with other user, And each user can update his name with other name that doesn't exists, And each user can delete his name with his uid from database. Its usernames system, hope you got it and can help me

Comment: The value you're writing in the screenshot is **not** the UID. It is a JSON object that contains the UID. To get to the structure you have in your question, change the Data to `"xx"`.

Comment: I've did "snapshot.ref.removeValue()", but i got error "setValue: or removeValue: at /user_lookup failed: permission_denied"